# Working with excel sheets in python 3.4

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlrd

Well i am completely stuck in reading an excel sheet(beginner with python)....I have 3 columns in an excel sheet say (`A`, `B` and `C`) with `n` number of rows in each of them ....so how can i possibly create a loop which iterates over all the rows till it reaches the end and write the content in a text file(.txt)....number of rows being same for all 3 columns....help please

code I'm using to open up the excel sheet is :

```
    import xlrd
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
```

Code used:

```
num_rows = worksheet.nrows - 1
num_cells = worksheet.ncols - 1
curr_row = -1
while curr_row < num_rows:
    curr_row += 1
    row = worksheet.row(curr_row)
    curr_cell = -1
    while curr_cell < num_cells:
        curr_cell += 1
        cell_value = worksheet.cell_value(curr_row, curr_cell)
        print (cell_value)
```

Comment: You don't seem to have tried anything beyond opening the sheet?

Comment: @wRAR added the code i was using...but i m not able to (add parameters) upto which i have to read the particular table in excel sheet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code follows your code will be:

```
textfile=open(filenameOfTextFile, 'w')

rows=sheet.nrows
for row in range(rows):
    textfile.write(sheet.cell(row,0).value + "," + sheet.cell(row,1).value + "," + sheet.cell(row,2).value + "\n")
```

Comment: thnks Fumu 7 ... but this code pops an error :   textfile.write(sheet.cell(row,0) + "," + sheet.cell(row,1) + "," + sheet.cell(row,2) + "\n")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Cell' and 'str'

Comment: It's my fault. 'value' attribute of cell provides cell's contents. I corrected code in my answer.

Comment: thnks @Fumu 7...can u tell me how to add some parameters to read the rows....for instance if i have to read only the row under column heading "A" ...?

Comment: sheet.cell(r,c) reffers a cell at r-th row and c-th column.  Cells of ("A" & number) are reffered by cells(number,0). cell takes two argumetn, row and columu, no other parameter is applicable.